# Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement])

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In reactjs how do I dynamically update the QR code component when props change. I'm using this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/kjua

`componentWillMount()` function is working on first load but it doesn't get updated but if I render `{this.state.el}` then I would get: `*react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLImageElement])`. If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.*

````js
  ```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import kjua from "kjua";
    
    class QrCodeOnAmountEntered extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          el: kjua({
            text: `amount=${
              this.props.text
            }&memo=xxxx`
          }),
          amount: this.props.text
        };
      }
      
      componentWillMount(){
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(this.state.el);
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
            QrCodeOnAmountEntered amount: {this.props.text}
            
    <p>Print QRCode here:</p>{this.state.el}
            
          </React.Fragment>
        );
      }
    }
    
    
    export default QrCodeOnAmountEntered; ```
````

I need to be able to dynamically update the QRCode when props amount value changed.

Comment: `QrCodeOnAmountEntered amount: {this.props.text}` must be `<QrCodeOnAmountEntered amount={this.props.text}/>`

Comment: That didn't work. Getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving props to state is a react anti-pattern (in the case of `props.text` => `this.state.amount`), and use of `componentWillMount` isn't recommended, but instead use `componentDidMount` to issue side-effects after the component mounts.

I tried looking at the docs for `kjua` but it seems pretty dated. I assume you pass it some 'text' and it returns an QR code image of that text.  [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) appears to not be renderable in react as an object, but perhaps `,src` will allow you to render it into an `<img>` tag.

```
render() {
  const { el } = this.state;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      QrCodeOnAmountEntered amount: {this.props.text}
      <p>Print QRCode here:</p>
      {el && <img src={el.src}/>}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Assuming calls to `kjua` with text data returns a new image, then you want to use `componentDidUpdate` to check that new props have arrived, and if so, get new QR image and save to state:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
  // if current text value is not equal to the previous, calculate
  // and save new QR code image in el, else ignore
  if (prevProps.text !== this.props.text) {
    const newQRcode = kjua({ text: `amount=${this.props.text}&memo=xxxx` });
    this.setState({ el: newQRcode });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew! The componentDidUpdate  causes a loop: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: That's why you must use a conditional test to **only** set state when a **new** state or prop value arrives.

Comment: isn't this the conditional which I'm already using: componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.amount !== this.props.text) {
      const newQRcode = kjua({ text: `amount=${this.props.text}&memo=xxxx` });
      console.log(prevProps.amount);
      console.log(this.props.text);
      console.log(newQRcode);
      this.setState({ el: newQRcode });
    }
    console.log("compared failed");
  }

Comment: `amount` is never a value you pass on props from what I can tell, so `prevProps.amount !== this.props.text` will *always* evaluate to true.  You only set `this.state.amount` in your constructor.  Notice, it's in `this.state`.  If you want your check to be `prevState.amount !== this.props.text`, then you also need to store `this.props.text` into `this.state.amount` so that conditional will only evaluate true when a new different `props.text` comes in.  Saving props to state is a react anti-pattern though, that's why you can just compare `prevProps` with current `this.props`.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Drew. It is working. Am I following the right standard below? constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      el: null,
      amount: this.props.amount
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevState, prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.amount !== this.props.amount) {
      const newQRcode = kjua({ text: `amount=${this.props.amount}&memo=xxxx` });
      console.log(prevProps.amount);
      console.log(this.props.amount);
     
    //  console.log(newQRcode);
     this.setState({ el: newQRcode, amount: this.props.amount });
    }

  }